# getting error while building substrate blockchain?

Tags: error, build, compile, polkadot-sdk

I have cloned polkadot-sdk version 1.1.0. When I try to build binary it is throwing error. Can you please tell why  I am getting error as I have not changed anything in codebase yet.
rust versions using. ==> 1.72.0
nightly version. ==>  1.75.0

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Always copy the error messages as text when submitting questions to sites like this.

Comment: What commands are you trying to run?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has already told you.

Need a `&[..]`.

Try call `.as_slice()` on your `BoundedVec` type.

Comment: AurevoirXavier,  isn't the template building from a clean checkout?